# How to serve static files from from a specific directory on a WordPress site running via Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a WordPress site running on Nginx. In my configuration, I have a location block like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

What I want to do is have a special directory full of static content. If a URL matches a file in the static directory, I want it to be served instead of the Wordpress content.

I won't know the names of the files ahead of time.

I tried changing my location block to

```
location / {
    try_files /static/$uri /static/$uri/ $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

This mostly does what I want (as long as `static` is a directory under `$document_root`), but it rewrites the url the visitor sees. I'd like to avoid that if possible. E.g., avoid `https://example.com/catalog.php` redirecting to `https://example.com/static/catalog.php`. I just want Nginx to serve the content from static without the visitor knowing.

---

I might not have been especially clear.

My WordPress content is located in `/srv/www/mysite/html` and my Nginx config is roughly like this:

```
server {
    root /srv/www/mysite/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

I have another folder, `/home/dave/static`, with arbitrary content in it. Say it has a file called `catalog.html`. If a visitor visits `https://example.com/catalog.html`, I want the content from `/home/dave/static/catalog.html` served. If there is no matching static file, I want to fallback to the WordPress content.

Here is something else I've tried in the meantime:

```
server {
    root /srv/www/mysite/html;

    location / {
        root /home/dave/static;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }
    location @fallback {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

This config doesn't work. It doesn't seem to recognize any of the static content and only serves WordPress content.

Comment: Use Nginx's location statements to define a location dependent on what the URL looks like. E.g. `location /static { stuff here; }` and then your `location / { stuff here; }`

Comment: @Kinnectus Won't this require the visitor to navigate to example.com/static/file? I want the visitor to navigate to example.com/file, but I want the content from the static directory to be served if it exists

Comment: You have some `/`s in the wrong place. Try: `try_files /static$uri $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks. I forgot to include the initial slash in my question. I did have it in my config. You're right that the slash after `static` was wrong. Unfortunately, this config still physically redirects the visitor to the /static directory rather than just serving content from there.

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions on the files in the static directory, and correct access for the Nginx worker to the directories above it? You do not state the OS, but some (e.g. Centos) have additional access controls.

Comment: @RichardSmith I believe so, it has the same ownership, permissions, and selinux security contexts as the wordpress directory. The `nginx` user is able to stat the directory. I have also tried using `/srv/www/mysite/static` as well so it shares the same parent directory.

Comment: Obviously there is a `location ~ \.php$` block, but are there any other regular expression locations that may conflict with the files in the `static` folder.

Comment: @RichardSmith That was it. I had additional rules specified because of a caching plugin. They interfered with what I was trying to do.